# How to make rabbitmq to refuses messages when a queue is full?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I have a http server which receives some messages and must reply 200 when a message is successfully stored in a queue and 500 is the message is not added to the queue.

I would like rabbitmq to refuse my messages when the queue reach a size limit.

How can I do it?

Comment: In short, you are trying to provide synchronous interface to asynchronous feature. There are no definitive way to do this, afaik. Don't be confused with [dead-lettering](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) and [queue length limit](https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html), messages are deleted from the front of queue (oldest messages will be dropped first). It may happens that in current situation RabbitMQ doesn't fit architectural requirements or you have to design architecture in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually you can't configure RabbitMq is such a way. but you may programatically check queue size like:

```
`DeclareOk queueOkStatus = channel.queueDeclare(queueOutputName, true, false, false, null);
if(queueOkStatus.getMessageCount()==0){//your logic here}`
but be careful, because this method returns number of non-acked messages in queue.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be aware of this , you can check Q count before inserting. It sends request on the same channel. Asserting Q returns messageCount which is Number of 'Ready' Messages. Note : This does not include the messages in unAcknowledged state.

If you do not wish to be aware of the Q length, then as specified in 1st comment of the question:

[x-max-length](https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html) : 
How many (ready) messages a queue can contain before it starts to drop them from its head.
(Sets the "x-max-length" argument.)